# set SwiftUI keyboardShortcut from a Int Variable

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to set a keyboard shortcut in swiftUI in a loop from the indexvariable.

My Code (commented Line) does not compile.

```
  var body: some View {
    ForEach (1...5, id: \.self) { index in
      Button("\(index)"){print("\(index) pressed")}
        //.keyboardShortcut("\(index)", modifiers: [.command])
    }
  }
}
```

How is that done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Yrb s solutution compiles, but does not work as expected, because UnicodeScalar(index) is interpreted as unicode with number index.

This worked for me:

```
struct BList: View {

  var body: some View {
    VStack{
      ForEach (1...5, id: \.self) { index in
        Button("\(index)"){print("\(index) pressed")}
          .keyboardShortcut(KeyEquivalent(Character(UnicodeScalar(0x0030+index)!)) , modifiers: [.command])
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to turn the index which is an Int into a Character and then to a KeyEquivalent. I force unwrapped the UnicodeScalar as it returns an optional, but for this example, where we are guaranteed an Int, it shouldn't be a problem. But know that it is there.

```
var body: some View {
    ForEach (1...5, id: \.self) { index in
      Button("\(index)"){print("\(index) pressed")}
        .keyboardShortcut(KeyEquivalent(Character(UnicodeScalar(index)!)), modifiers: [.command])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have limited index range you can do this:

```
var body: some View {
    ForEach (1...5, id: \.self) { index in
      Button("\(index)"){print("\(index) pressed")}
        .keyboardShortcut(["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"][index])
    }
}
```